# Elasticsearch Run Node Client and index data in memory

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to run elasticsearch with my tomcat server and index the data pulling from database and put it in elasticsearch index. Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch has a Java API that you can use to do what you want to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/index.html

If you are new to ES Definitive Guide is a very very good document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html

By the way Elasticsearch is a full-text search engine. If you are looking an in memory data solution may be you should consider something like Apache Ignite: http://ignite.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have an existing implementation with some elastic search plugin. I need to upgrade it.